# Remove highlight and "NEW" tag of freshly installed programs

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Is there any way to remove the highlighting and the "NEW" tag from the list of applications on Windows 8.1?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to be possible. The [registry edit](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-highlighting-newly-installed-apps-in-windows-8-1-apps-screen/) no longer works.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it doesn't work. But that doesn't mean it's impossible entirely... I hope.

Comment: From @Joshua: Try this on the windows 8 forums: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/44786-new-apps-message-start-remove-windows-8-1-a.html

Comment: His answer should have not been deleted, it was the most useful info yet.

Comment: @Francisc It was, however, not an answer according to our standards. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/157730) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/157730) (both on [meta.se]) as well as the "Provide context for links" section of [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center for more discussion on this.

Comment: You can invoke rules and ignore the fact that it was a genuinely useful answer, but I think that's wrong. The whole point of this website is to answer questions. Enforcing some artificial rules should be much less imporant.

Comment: @Francisc: Link-only answers aren't acceptable as a long-time member like you should very well know. If you feel that manual method makes for a good answer, feel free to note the relevant parts from that linked article here in your own words with proper attribution. As you know self-answers are allowed and encouraged here, and can even be self-accepted.